Route IIS Web traffic to different website (same name) on a different server based on URL
We have a multi-tenant website (IIS) and want to route some customers to a dedicated version of the website running on a different server. We don't want to change the base URL so that we don't impact customers.
Would something like this be possible?
customer1.myapp.mycompany.com goes to myapp on IP address: 11.2.3.5
customer2.myapp.mycompany.com goes to myapp on IP address: 11.2.3.8
I don't think IIS rewrite rules would work because they would exist on one of the servers and we'd want to reroute the traffic before it hits IIS. We use a Windows environment (not AWS or Azure).
I was thinking of something like a load balancer before IIS machines that routes based on some string in the URL.

Mistake 3 in https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

This link should help you about how to config the arr: Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing.
